# How to add a element to HTML5 code with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a problem with a JavaScript code. I am beginner in programming so I ask to help me. So what this script must do?
After clicking the submit button it must write on site a value of two form fields.
This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl_PL">
<head>
<title>KidGifter</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list_help">
    <img id="smile_help" src="img/smile.png">
    <div id="info-form">
    <p id="l_h_title">Hejka!</p>
    <p id="l_h_text">Tutaj możesz stworzyć swoją liste prezentów i udostępnić ją na Facebooku lub Twitterze. Niech twoi znajomi i bliscy wiedzą co chcesz dostać!</p>
    <p id="l_h_formtitle">Najpierw wprowadź nazwę prezentu:</p>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="formtitle">
    <p id="l_h_formdesc">A teraz możesz krótko go opisać:</p>
    <textarea id="formdescription" maxlength="230"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="+ Dodaj" id="sub" />
    </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is JavaScript code :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
    var f2 = document.getElementById("f2");
    var submit = document.getElementById("sub");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    submit.onclick = function() {
        html = "";
        html += "<div class='gift'>";
        html += "<div class='gifttext'>";
        html += "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + f1.value + "</p>";
        html += "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + f2.value + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        body.appendChild(html);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for help ! :)

Comment: .appendChild expects a DOM element, not a string. Also, getElementsByTagName returns a list of nodes, not a single node. To get the body, just use `document.body`.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a DOM element, put the rest of your HTML in that DOM element and use that DOM element for `.appendChild()` like this.  `appendChild()` doesn't take a string, it takes a DOM element.  Also, your `body` variable wasn't correct.  Here's a fixed up version:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
    var f2 = document.getElementById("f2");
    var submit = document.getElementById("sub");
    submit.onclick = function () {
        var html = "<div class='gifttext'>";
        html += "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + f1.value + "</p>";
        html += "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + f2.value + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "gift";
        div.innerHTML = html;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Itemized changes:

1. Declare `html` variable as a local variable so it's not an implicit global.
2. Remove the outer div from your HTML string.
3. Create the outer div with `document.createElement("div")`.
4. Assign the desired class name to that div.
5. Assign the HTML to the `.innerHTML` property of the div that was just created.
6. Append that div to the `document.body` object.
7. Remove code that was obtaining the `body` variable (it was wrong and `document.body` already exists as a shortcut reference to the body object).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, since your new to javascript, to look up jquery, it is a library that makes things like this much easier.

```
var aDiv= document.createElement('div');
//// create p blah blah
aDiv.className = "giftText";
body.appendChild(aDiv);
```

but with jquery it works more like this.

```
$('body').append($('<div class="giftText">);
```

Comment: What is the `addClass` property?  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: "since your new to javascript, to look up jquery" this is the worst you could suggest for beginner.

Comment: I wouldnt see it that way, showing them a way to do the tasks easier than with standard javascript.  It makes things much easier for new devs, but I respect your opinion, thanks for the input

Comment: The popular convention here on StackOverflow is to not offer a jQuery solution unless the OP asked for it via a reference in the text or a jQuery tag.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know, but I did offer the solution in standard javascript and just gave my opinion about jquery.  But I will keep that in mind in the future.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

here's a working jsfiddle of the code from your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/hxsFH/

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="list_help">
        <img id="smile_help" src="img/smile.png">
        <div id="info-form">
            <p id="l_h_title">Hejka!</p>
            <p id="l_h_text">Tutaj możesz stworzyć swoją liste prezentów i udostępnić ją na Facebooku lub Twitterze. Niech twoi znajomi i bliscy wiedzą co chcesz dostać!</p>
            <p id="l_h_formtitle">Najpierw wprowadź nazwę prezentu:</p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="formtitle" />
                <p id="l_h_formdesc">A teraz możesz krótko go opisać:</p>
                <textarea id="formdescription" maxlength="230"></textarea>
                <input type="button" value="+ Dodaj" id="sub" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("formtitle");
var f2 = document.getElementById("formdescription");
var submit = document.getElementById("sub");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
submit.onclick = function () {
    html = "";
    html += "<div class='gift'>";
    html += "<div class='gifttext'>";
    html += "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + f1.value + "</p>";
    html += "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + f2.value + "</p>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = html;
    body.appendChild(d);
    return false;
}
```